# How do I fetch data without refreshing Youtube video on current page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on an PHP application wherein I am playing YouTube videos on my website. The URL, start_time and end_time of each video are stored in database and after every 30 seconds, I check for all values in database if the current_time is between start_time and end_time of any row and if it is, then fetch URL from that row and start video.

```
$retrieval = "select * from video where user_id=$id AND prog_id=$p";    
$result= mysqli_query($db,$retrieval);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $fromTime = strtotime($row['start_time']);
      $toTime = strtotime($row['end_time']);
      $inputTimeT = strtotime($currTime);
      if($inputTimeT >= $fromTime and $inputTimeT <= $toTime){
           $url = $row['video_url'];
           if(preg_match('/https:\/\/(www\.)*youtube\.com\/.*/',$url)){
                // Fetch YouTube VideoID from URL
                preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $match);
                $youtube_id = $match[1];
       ?>
           <iframe class="mainvideo" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $youtube_id?>?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=<?php echo $youtube_id?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <?php 
            }
            else{?>
                <video width="100%" src="<?php echo $row['video_url']?>" controls loop autoplay>
          <!--ALTERNATE VIDEOS   -->
               </video>
          <?php  }
           } 
        }
  }
```

If I refresh page every minute, the video plays again from start(if time is not up).
I want to perform this operation every minute without reloading the page and without reloading currently played YouTube Video(if its time is not up). If possible, please provide a possible solution to this problem.

P.S. I have validated the start and end time while storing into database, so each video have unique start and end time and they dont operlap.

Comment: well you used the right tags; where is the code that you tried?

Comment: Normally what you would do, is to have the logic for fetching the video from your database via PHP in a seperate file, then use AJAX to parse and retrieve data between your original file and the file that handles the PHP. You can then load in the video with whatever time you want. Alternatively, you can build everything around the video in AJAX. That way you have 100% control over what to refresh, and what not to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Well whenever you want to fetch data without reloading the load, AJAX is what comes to aid.

What I would have done(don't know if best practice or even a bad practice) is:

1. Make my server code in some other php file
2. Send data to that file(if necessary) and retrieve data using ajax
3. Make changes to HTML page in javaScript

Comment: Well, I tried with jQuery AJAX load on the video tag, also copied server code code on different file but every 5 seconds the video is refreshed, not the page. I dont want video to be refreshed if it is the same as currently been playing.